# fprofile-arcs ftest-coverage performance overhead gcc

Tags: gcc

Is there any overhead in terms of performance If I compile using  -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage flags in gcc.

I am interested in unittest coverage but doesn't want a separate build process for the same.